# Can Branch.io fallback to a different app

Tags: android, ios, deep-linking, branch.io

I am currently developing a new app to replace my old mobile app. The old and new mobile app will both exist at the same time to give the customers time to transition from the old to new app. The old mobile app is using branch.io for deep linking and I would like to continue using those deep links for my new mobile app. Is there a way to make the deep link:

1. Open the new mobile app if it is install
2. If the new mobile app is not installed, open the old mobile app
3. If both the new and old mobile app are not installed, direct the user to the new mobile app listing in the store

As you can see, I would like my deep link to try to open the new app and have the old app as a fallback. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution:

### Android:

1. Create a new Branch app with a new link domain for your new app.
2. Use a Quick link from the old app as the fallback URL for the new app.
3. On the old app, change the fallback url to the appstore listing of the new app.

Note: I was having some issues with making the fallback url be the new app listing so you may have to keep it the old app listing. You will just have to play around with it a bit.

### iOS:

For iOS you can either do the same thing you did for android or simply add your bundle id to the list of bundle ids in your branch.io configuration.

Note: The above solutions pass on the initial deep link parameters.